# How to stop killing browser by terminal

Tags: ssh, grep, kill

I am using Ubuntu. my friend is killing my browser from his ubuntu machine using terminal. He knows my password. Do let me know any way to stop this killing process. I know that changing the password will be the solution. But I want to know the other ways to stop it. He is doing it via SSH.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include what he is using to do it?

Comment: he is killing my browser, skype etc by ps -ef |grep firefox, skype etc and kill it. i want to stop this killing process

Answer (score 2):

Since your *friend* is connecting via SSH:

Blocking the IP address might be a bad idea, i assume that you have some DHCP server running in your LAN -> the attacker's IP address will change eventually.

You could also block him based on the MAC address, that will however only work when he is connecting from the same sub-net.

**I recommend you to change the password, since that is the root of the problem.**

As an alternative you could disallow your own user to login via `ssh` and create a new user that you use for connecting to your computer. Of course you must not give that users's password to that friend of yours, that's self explaining. (Once connected with the new user you can use the `su` command to switch into your original user)

There are of course a lot of other solutions for your problem, but i **really** suggest you just to change the password.

**Update**

To disable `SSH` access edit `sshd_config` (`vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config`) and
search for `DenyUsers`. If there is no such entry add it in a new line, so will end up with the following: `DenyUsers <the-username-to-block>`

Now restart the `sshd` daemon : `sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart`

Now add a new user with `adduser <some-new-name>`. Once connected with the new user use `su <your original username>` to switch into your original user's context.

Comment: Thanks @ortang, is there any link regarding this answer. Please do let me know.

Comment: That depends on what you want to do, please explain

Comment: i want to stop the ability of that user in killing my browser, skype etc... Thanks in advance

Comment: Your friend is using `your` username to connect does he not(since you are talking about that user)? I updated my answer with a possible solution. Another thing: I guess your friend has physical access to your computer? He can always log in locally and **undo** whatever you do to block him out, keep that in mind. That's why i suggest you to just change that password of yours ;)

Answer (score 1):

The other way is to stop the ssh daemon, which disables remote logins to the machine, so be careful about that.

```
sudo service ssh stop
```

However, changing your password is better.

Comment: That is assuming the joker connects by ssh, not by any remote control app.

Comment: yes he connects by SSH

Comment: @ipip i've got this result
sudo: /etc/init.d/sshd: command not found

Comment: @blue The SSH service name is `ssh`. Barafu, I've updated your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use UFW GUI to turn on firewall, then block all network connections to his IP.

Comment: How to perform this? Please let me know